# htaccess "this page has too many redirects " Redirect loop Error

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have searched across stackoverflow, since my problem is specific, couldnt find anywhere, so posting it here. Hope one of us can suggest the resolution.
This is my htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm getting the following error in chrome:

**"this page has too many redirects "  Redirect loop Error.**

This happens often which means not everytime, but more often.
Can anyone tell me whats the issue with above htaccess code?

Thanks.

Comment: Your htaccess looks ok.
Clear your browser's caches.

Comment: There are no other rules?

Comment: yeah, this is the only content in .htaccess

Comment: What's the URL you are visiting? It could be something else other than htaccess. Have you tried disabling plugins, changing theme, and of course clearing your cache like @starkeen mentioned?